# FOL Paradox Translation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm working on a translation exercise for FOL using existential and universal quantifiers, but it's proving rather tricky. Below I'll attach the expressions and the question.

P(x) : ___x is person

D(x) : ___x drinks beer

(The domain is the bar.)

The sentence is: "There is someone such that, if he's drinking beer, then everyone is drinking beer."

So I'm a bit unsure of where to start. I'm sorry this probably isn't the best use of the math stack exchange but my teacher isn't being very helpful. I would be thankful for some help with this problem!

My thinking:

∃x (D(x)→∀y D(y))

I'm not sure if (or how) I should be integrating P(x)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely off to a good start with $\exists x (D(x) \to \forall y D(y))$. The question is related to the notion of [restricted quantifiers](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Restricted_quantifier).

What you want to say is "there exists a person $x$ such that $(D(x) \to $ for every person $y$, $D(y))$". In other words, you want to switch from $\exists x$ to "$\exists$ a person $x$", and $\forall y$ to "$\forall$ persons $y$".

To be more precise, we interpret "there exists a person $x$ such that $Q(x)$" to mean "there exists $x$ such that $(x$ is a person and $Q(x))$. And we interpret "for all persons $y$, $Q(y)$" to mean "for all $y$, $(y$ is a person $\to Q(y))$".

I can't say too much more without totally giving the answer away.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! I'll keep working on it, but I might come back for the answer of this practice exercise if I'm having no luck! Thanks again